CheckDuplicatesRunnable when building Android Project (Jetpack Compose)
It's been three days since I got stuck with this annoying error Android Studio logs whenever I build the project: "Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
".
I've read on the internet the error occurs because of different versions of the same library, which makes sense, because everything was working well until I tried to display the current speed the user is travelling at in a composable TextView. I'm following the MVVM presentation pattern and, as I said, it worked well until I began to import "FusedLocationProviderClient", "LocationRequest", "LiveData" and others. I believe I imported different versions of the same library, because in this Android world everything is deprecated and many functions, methods and properties don't exist from one version to another. It is indeed overwhelming and makes me want to quit Android development, as I presume many other developers want to do as well. I've seen this video of Philip Lackner on YouTube where he explains that it makes no sense switching from Android development to any other type of programming just because "the grass is greener on the other side". I agree with him; if you don't find fun in what you do because it is complex, you will not find it anywhere else. However, what I feel when I develop Android apps is an extreme frustration because if I fix one thing, another thing "breaks".
Anyway, if you can help me out to solve the problem, I appreciate it. Here's my build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
namespace = "com.albertoalvarezportero.autocontrol"
compileSdk = 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.albertoalvarezportero.autocontrol"
    minSdk = 24
    targetSdk = 34
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
}
packaging {
    resources {
        excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"


    }
}
}

dependencies {

implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
implementation(libs.play.services.location)
implementation(libs.compose.preview.renderer)
testImplementation(libs.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)

//Lifecycle ViewModel
implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose){} // Correct ViewModel dependency
implementation(libs.androidx.runtime.livedata)  // For LiveData in Compose

}

Thank you very much!
